# How to fetch records from mysql database in sorted order with pagination along with group by status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table e.g. `Employee`, which has columns `(id, name, is_active)`.

I want to fetch the records from `employee` table sorted by `name` along with pagination.

```
SELECT * from employee ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 5, 10;
```

In above query `5` count to `skip` first 5 records and take next `10` records.

I want to make a query which will return all records which has value `is_active=1`, followed by records which has value `is_active = 0` with pagination.

**e.g:** I have 50 records out of them 40 records has value `is_active=1`, and 10 records which has value `is_active=0`.
So as I am using pagination and page size is suppose `10 records per page`.

So query will return all **active records** first with order by **name** and at last page will return 10 **inactive** records order by name.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need descendingly sort by `is_active` column, and no need an `OFFSET` value depending on the explanation such as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM employee 
 ORDER BY is_active DESC, name 
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros, its working as expected.
I am fetching records in pagination so offset will be required. I checked your solution adding offset as well, its working as expected.